# Asynchronous NSURLConnection with NSOperation

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsurlconnection, nsoperation, nsinvocation

I want to do `NSURLConnection`  in background mode,because it  response is having much data.Forums are telling to use Apple's finite length coding to use in `didEnterBackground`.
but I want to avoid it.instead of it I use following code through `NSOperation` with `NSInvocation` as, but it is not working.`connectToServer` is having `NSURLConnection` operation.any help please?`didReceiveData`,`didReceiveResponse` delegate methods are not called?

```
 NSOperationQueue *queue = [NSOperationQueue new];

NSInvocationOperation *operation = [[NSInvocationOperation alloc] initWithTarget:self
                                                                        selector:@selector(connectToServer)
                                                                          object:nil];

[queue addOperation:operation];
[operation release];
[queue autorelease];

 -(void)connectToServer
{
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"];
NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
NSURLConnection *theConnection = [[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self] autorelease];

    if( theConnection )
    {
        webData = [[NSMutableData data] retain];
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"theConnection is NULL");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 42, accepted):

This kind of question was asked a zillion time. Delegates are not getting called because as of iOS 4 operations are started on a secondary thread. The thread probably exits before the delegates are called that's all.

Keep the connection on the main thread and handle the data in a background thread using GCD.

I'v wrote about all this stuff here : http://cocoaintheshell.com/2011/04/nsurlconnection-synchronous-asynchronous/

EDIT : Updated link.

Comment: enjoy my hard earned 50 votes.u should have answered before my bounty :)

Comment: can you please tell how to stop Runloop and port?

Comment: [runLoop removePort:PORT forMode:MODE];
CFRunLoopStop(CFRunLoopGetCurrent());

Comment: Thanks a lot @Nyx0uf, you save me a lot of time...! Great contribution!

Comment: I don't think that this is a solution, the answer is a workaround, but not the solution to the problem.

Answer (score 6):

Apple provides `QHTTPOperation`, which does just what you want, encapsulates an `NSURLConnection` within an `NSOperation`, for a single request. You can find it in Apple's [sample code](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/MVCNetworking/Listings/Networking_QHTTPOperation_h.html).

`QHTTPOperation` is actually a subclass of `QRunLoopOperation` which lets you encapsulate logic which depends on run-loop callbacks in an NSOperation.

The 3rd party `ASIHTTPRequest` is a similar popular solution, AFAIK it is no longer maintained though.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the sendAsynchronousRequest:queue:completionHandler: method documented [here in Apple's Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001697-DontLinkElementID_1).  It allows asynchronous requests with NSURLConnection.

Note this requires iOS5 or higher

Comment: The first link I had was for the Mac, I have updated it for the iOS version.  Are you wanting the Mac reference?  The Mac documentation can be found here: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001697-DontLinkElementID_1

Comment: i want to do in iOS4..please answer to my question why it is not working?