# ASynchronous NSURLConnection inside NSOperation with NSInvocation?

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsurlconnection, nsoperation, nsinvocation

I have to use Asynchrnous NSURLConnection inside NSOPeration  in background mode,because its  response is having large  dataI have to avoid  Apple's finite length coding to use in didEnterBackground.instead of it I use following code through NSOperation with NSInvocation as, but it is not working.connectToServer is having NSURLConnection operation.any help please?didReceiveData,didReceiveResponse delegate methods are not called?

```
 -(void)viewDidLoad
 {
 NSOperationQueue *queue = [NSOperationQueue new];

NSInvocationOperation *operation = [[NSInvocationOperation alloc] initWithTarget:self
                                                                        selector:@selector(connectServer)
                                                                          object:nil];

[queue addOperation:operation];
[operation release];
[queue autorelease];
```

}

```
 -(void)connectServer
{


NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"];
NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
NSURLConnection *theConnection = [[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self] autorelease];

    if( theConnection )
    {
        webData = [[NSMutableData data] retain];
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"theConnection is NULL");
    }
}
```

}

Comment: possible duplicate of [Asynchronous NSURLConnection with NSOperation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9223537/asynchronous-nsurlconnection-with-nsoperation)

Comment: is the connectServer method being called?

Answer (score 2):

mmmm maybe you could do the connection inside a block for the main queue with this:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

        NSURLRequest *request = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReturnCacheDataElseLoad timeoutInterval:10.0];
        _connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request startImmediately:YES];
        [request release];
});
```

and then the delegate methods should get called.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you want run NSURLConnection on secondary thread , you need to add that connection to runloops

```
NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

    NSURLRequest *request = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url 
                cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReturnCacheDataElseLoad timeoutInterval:10.0];
    _connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self
                 startImmediately:YES];
    [request release];


[_connection scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
[_connection start];

    [pool release];
```

Answer (score 0):

I might be wrong about this, but still wil try...

See the docs say... for `start` method

> start Causes the connection to begin loading data, if it has not
>   already.
>
> - (void)start Discussion Calling this method is necessary only if you create a connection with the
>     initWithRequest:delegate:startImmediately: method and provide NO for
>     the startImmediately parameter. If you don’t schedule the connection
>     in a run loop or an operation queue before calling this method, the
>     connection is scheduled in the current run loop in the default mode.

so it seems to me you will have to the start the connection manually as it is inside an operation queue.
correct me if I am wrong.